# navigate back to same scene with updated data in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux in my application.

I'm navigating to same scene with different props. When I press back, it's showing old data.

How can I solve this ?

This is my code:

In componentwillmount I'm calling action.

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.actions.singleCar(this.props.carId);
}
```

Here I'm navigating to same scene with different ID.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.NewCarFeatures({ carId:
    singleCarModel.id })}>
    <Text> Scene A </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: override componentWillReceiveProps() method as follows - 
`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp)`.

Now you can use the nextProp object to call setState on your previous component and that will refresh its UI (when you update state).

Comment: back navigation does not render anything.

Answer (score 0):

Actions.refresh(PARAMS) that will update the properties of the current screen.

Comment: Where should I add this ?